# SQL joins: group with order

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got a database with 4 tables, as below:

```
USER table:
 * id: INTEGER, AUTO INCREMENT...
 * name: VARCHAR

PRODUCT table:
 * id: INTEGER, AUTO INCREMENT...
 * name: VARCHAR


ORDER table:
 * id: INTEGER, AUTO INCREMENT...
 * number: VARCHAR
 * user_id: FOREIGN KEY to USER table
 * date_created: DATETIME

ORDER_TO_PRODUCT table:
 * order_id: FOREIGN KEY to ORDER table
 * product_id: FOREIGN KEY to PRODUCT table
 * quantity: INTEGER
```

I want to create a query that would list all users, each of them having it's last order made (according to `order.date_created`) date and number.

My idea is to group all results by users (to make one row for each user) and then to order by order date. However, this doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT u.name, o.date_created, o.number
FROM order o
INNER JOIN user u ON o.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY o.user_id
ORDER BY o.created DESC
```

The question is - am I doing it wrong? And is that possible to achieve the goal *without subqueries*?

Comment: I think you need to add a subquery, but am curious what others are suggesting.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @genespos I just get them sorted the wrong way. It seems like the GROUP phase is executed as the first one, random rows are put into each group, and then goes ORDER BY phase, which orders those incorrect elements.

Comment: You don't have aggregate function,, At what is the group by o.user_id?

Comment: can we assume that the latest order also has the highest id?

Comment: UGroup by is executed before order by. How can you say that are grouped random rows? Try inserting also user_id in select and have a look to what happens

Comment: @maraca no, no assumptions like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query needs to know what to do with `u.name`, `o.date_created` and `o.number`. An `ORDER BY` is not enough. The only field you can currently address without an aggregating function is `o.user_id`, since this is your `GROUP BY`.

To find the last order made, you usually need to use Window functions like `PARTITION OVER`. But if your date_created and number are ordered naturally, you can also use a simple `MAX`

`SELECT o.user_id, MAX(u.name), MAX(o.date_created), MAX(o.number)
FROM order o
INNER JOIN user u ON o.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY o.user_id`

Otherwise check this documentation for Window functions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-window.html